# Image show in full screen mode

Tags: android

I have created an app in which images are showing on the gridview, I want when I click on a particular image it show on full screen on the next page.

I have write down code, but when I am clicking on the image,it is crashing.

Please somebody help me

```
public class GridViewActivity extends Activity {        

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

                long imageId = (Long) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);

                Intent fullScreenIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(),FullScreenImage.class);

                fullScreenIntent.putExtra("Hello",imageId); 

                startActivity(fullScreenIntent); 

            }
        });


       /* gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(GridViewActivity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });*/
    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context mContext;

        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return images.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imageView;
            if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
                imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
            } else {
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }

            imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);
            return imageView;
        }

        // references to our images
        private Integer[] images = {
                R.drawable.bluehills, R.drawable.sample_3,
                R.drawable.sample_7, R.drawable.sunset,
                R.drawable.waterlilies, R.drawable.winter,  

        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Help us help you. Post the code you're having trouble with along with the stack trace. Otherwise, we can't help.

Comment: paste the code of FullScreenImage.class

Comment: Logcat output for exception needed. And keep one thing in mind that whenever you get exception at that time post the code and logcat output.

Comment: this class is relatively ok, problem is in FullScreenImage.class

Comment: Thanks I have posted both the classes plz check it, where I m wrong

Comment: did you told the manifest that you are using fullscreen activity too in your application. Sometimes we forget to initialize it...:P

Comment: I have already initialized it

Comment: It is crashing 11-30 12:18:22.224: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(684): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-30 12:18:22.224: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(684): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer

Comment: try this link http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-gridview-layout-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

```
package com.image;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class ImageActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
 Integer[] mImageIds = { R.drawable.a, R.drawable.abc,
        R.drawable.fd, R.drawable.ft, R.drawable.gh, R.drawable.nat

};
ImageView im;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Gallery g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery1);
    im = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);


    g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    getWindow().addFlags( WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN );
    g.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,long id) {
            Toast.makeText(ImageActivity.this, "" + position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            im.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);                               
        }
    });     
}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    int mGalleryItemBackground;
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
        TypedArray a = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.HelloGallery);
        mGalleryItemBackground = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.HelloGallery_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
        a.recycle();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mImageIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);
        i.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
        i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 100));
        i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        i.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground);
        i.bringToFront();
        return i;
    }
}
 }
```

Comment: Thanks but its not working, I used GridView here dont want to use gallaery